# Do we use the article 'the' with geographical division names such as 'province', 'region', or 'oblast'?

Tags: definite-article

Is it correct to use 'the' in 'I live in the Ontario province' or 'I live in the Moscow oblast'? Should I be using the definite article 'the' with geographical division names?

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr:  Don't use "the".

Normally you only use the name of the district or city:

> I live in Ontario (but you also will hear *I live in the Province of Ontario*)

> I live in Moscow.

Sometimes this is ambiguous. Normally you don't add "the".

> I live in New York City.

> I live in New York State.

In the case of the "Moscow Oblast" this explicitly *excludes* Moscow.  How this is expressed is very subject to special cases and particular idiom.  In the case of places from non-English-speaking countries you also have to decide whether or not to translate.

> I live in the City of London.  (note that this excludes most of London)

> I live in Tokyo Prefecture. (This includes a lot of rural land, but excludes cities in the Greater Tokyo Megopolis. Prefecture is the conventional translation of *to*, or *ken*, or *fu*.)

In your particular case you could choose between:

> I live near Moscow (This is the easiest to understand for people who don't know Russia well)

> I live in the district surrounding Moscow.

> I live in Moscow Oblast (But many people will assume this is a Russian way of saying "in Moscow", and would be surprised to find you actually live in on a farm in *Kormovoe* 200km from the centre of Moscow)

> I live in Podmoskovye.  (But most people will find that meaningless)

Answer (score 1):

If the first part of the name (which I've bolded below) is a "common" adjective, then including a determiner (which I've italicized below) is usual and sometimes required:

> I live in *the* **Ninth** Ward.
> I live in *the* [**Eastern** District](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_District,_Hong_Kong).
> I live in *the* [**South** Province](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Province,_New_Caledonia).

Otherwise, the issue depends largely on the second part of the name. Some nouns do not require determiners<sup>1</sup>:

> I live in **Ontario** Province.
> I live in **Moscow** Oblast.
> I live in **Kowloon City** District.
> I live in **Jefferson** Parish.

While others are normally preceded by determiners:

> I live in *the* **Lombardy** Region.
> I live in *the* **Yukon** Territory.

Keep in mind that this is just general guidance. Requirements for determiners vary greatly among English proper nouns, and there is no rule that is guaranteed to always work.

---

Note 1: A determiner may still be included if it adds meaning. For example: "I live in *Canada's* **Ontario** Province."